# Gradle build resolves Maven2 snapshots differently than a Maven build

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I am using Nexus OSS 3.x and I have a custom library I am deploying to my Nexus repository using the nexus-staging-maven-plugin.  I deploy the snapshot using the maven deploy goal.  I can then include that snapshot as a dependency in the pom.xml of another Maven project and the correct timestamped snapshot gets resolved appropriately.  The problem is when I now try to include that snapshot dependency in a Gradle build, Gradle is trying to pull down the incorrect version.  I noticed in the maven-metadata.xml that's created, the Gradle is actually trying to resolve my-lib-2.0.0-20200225.163947-14.jar, whereas my Maven build correctly resolves to my-lib-2.0.0-20200225.163945-13.jar.  Here's what's in the maven-metadata.xml file:

```xml
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
   <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <versioning>
      <snapshot>
         <timestamp>20200225.163947</timestamp>
         <buildNumber>14</buildNumber>
      </snapshot>
      <lastUpdated>20200225163947</lastUpdated>
      <snapshotVersions>
         <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>2.0.0-20200225.163945-13</value>
            <updated>20200225163947</updated>
         </snapshotVersion>
         <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>2.0.0-20200225.163945-13</value>
            <updated>20200225163947</updated>
         </snapshotVersion>
         <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>pom</extension>
            <value>2.0.0-20200225.163945-13</value>
            <updated>20200225163947</updated>
         </snapshotVersion>
      </snapshotVersions>
   </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.  It turns out the nexus-staging-maven-plugin I was using was causing this.  I removed the plugin from my pom.xml (shown below) and defaulted down to the standard maven-deploy-plugin and it resolved the version discrepancies (also shown below)

**This is plugin I was using.  Removing it resolved my issues.**

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${nexus-staging-plugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-deploy</id>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**After removing the above nexus specific plugin, I now get consistent timestamps & build numbers on the snapshots:**

```xml
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
   <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <versioning>
      <snapshot>
         <timestamp>20200225.174453</timestamp>
         <buildNumber>22</buildNumber>
      </snapshot>
      <lastUpdated>20200225174453</lastUpdated>
      <snapshotVersions>
         <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>2.0.0-20200225.174453-22</value>
            <updated>20200225174453</updated>
         </snapshotVersion>
         <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>pom</extension>
            <value>2.0.0-20200225.174453-22</value>
            <updated>20200225174453</updated>
         </snapshotVersion>
         <snapshotVersion>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>2.0.0-20200225.174453-22</value>
            <updated>20200225174453</updated>
         </snapshotVersion>
      </snapshotVersions>
   </versioning>
</metadata>
```